# CD-R. Как снять ограничение "только на запись"?

Tags: диск, внешние-устройства

Имеется диск CD-R. Можно ли перезаписать на него файлы. То есть удалить существующие и записать новые?

Про то, что CD-R одноразовый знаю, но может все таки есть способ, может как то снять это ограничение "только на запись"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Только если на нем не закрыта сессия и есть свободное место - тогда их можно будет "удалить" и в проводнике они пропадут.

Файлы при этом с диска никуда не денутся и их можно будет прочитать специальным софтом.

Comment: а как всё это сделать, какими программами? приведите пример использования, пожалуйста